# Sulley - Logic behind primitives

Tags: fuzzing

**Are sulley's primitives used to build a description of the protocol or to specify what kind of data we want to generate?**

Let's take for instance the following primitive `s_string("ok", encoding="ascii")`

In the first case, it would mean, the protocol expects ascii strings, so I would expect sulley to generate ascii strings as well as non-ascii strings.

In the second case, it would mean, sulley must only generate ascii strings.
Which one is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Sulley manual](http://www.fuzzing.org/wp-content/SulleyManual.pdf),  it is the

```
Encoding to use for string
```

I think that's your second case.